# Forward copy of mail to different domain

Tags: postfix

Is it possible in post-fix to forward an Mail send from particular user From: abc@example.com TO:anyuser@ourcompany.com should forward copy of email to other user at external domain abc@somewhere.com, the original recipient should also get the email. only copy of the mail should be forwarded.

i.e 
From: abc@example.com 
TO:anyuser@ourcompany.com
Copy of message should receive to "abc@somewhere.com"

Comment: Have a look at http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc

Comment: @NickW: thank you very much.i tested and working fine.
can be the mail routed as mentioned above with out sending copy to original recipient ?

Comment: You might need to look into address rewriting in that case, always bcc is part of that, but there is a lot more you can do. http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Comment: Yes it can, but you need to read up a little to decide which method is best for you, is the domain you want to send to external (not hosted on the same machine)? You might want to use virtual alias maps http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#virtual.. if not, you may just want a normal alias..

Comment: @NickW :Will the address re-writing work for my scenario.
Mail originating from internet domain  abc@example.com sending to my domain  TO:anyuser@ourcompany.com which in turn i want to route to other email address which is in other domain "abc@somewhere.com" in internet

Comment: You could probably just do that with aliases then, do you use mysql or are your tables just classic text files?

Comment: @NickW: thank you ..I found the answer..

Put the below entry in check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

abc@example.com  redirect abc@somewhere.com

Comment: Glad you found the answer!